# How can I select all entries containing one of two values per user?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g, I have one table, pets. Pets has two columns, owner and type. The only types of pets in the table are dogs, cats and fish.

Some owners have two pets.

I want to select all of the owners that have both a cat and a dog.
How can I do that?

Comment: @Eric This was a fine question, hence it was not deleted. Stop being an elitist. I was trying to understand a concept. I didn't even have a query personally. I posted this hypothetical because I was trying to learn a new concept that I wasn't aware of. Look through this thread. Notice that every other person is being helpful and trying to help me, the OP to grasp the concept that I am asking about. What does it say about you that you're the only one with a problem.

Also, this question abides by all of the rules in the thread you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various different ways to do it, here's one:

```
select owner from pets where type = 'CAT'
intersect 
select owner from pets where type = 'DOG'
```

The INTERSECT operator produces a set of distinct owners of both cats and dogs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT t.owner
FROM tab t
WHERE t.type IN ('dog', 'cat')
GROUP BY t.owner
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.type) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagining a table like this:

```
|owner  ||  type|
-----------------
|own1   |   dog |
|own1   |   cat |
|own2   |   dog |
|own3   |   dog |
|own3   |   fish|
```

You could try something like this:

```
select o.cat_and_dog_owner
from(
    select t.owner as cat_and_dog_owner, sum(case when t.type = 'dog' then 1 else 0 end) as dog_cnt, sum(case when t.type = 'cat' then 1 else 0 end) as cat_cnt
    from table t
    where t.type in ('dog', 'cat')
    group by t.owner
    having (sum(case when t.type = 'dog' then 1 else 0 end) > 0) and (sum(case when t.type = 'cat' then 1 else 0 end) > 0)
) o
```

Basically you only want to select cat and dog records. The we use `sum` and `case` in conjunction to get a count of dogs and cats grouped by owner. Finally we check with the `having` clause to make sure we only get records where the count in both columns is greater than 0.